# excel autofill every third column

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a product specification sheet in Excel. Each specification is made up of three columns: for example, column A is 500, column B is yards and finally in Column C I test wether column A is set and then combine them into "500 yards". Column C is used in the product specifications.  As is column F, I and so on.

Now I know that I can use autofill to fill the entire column C, but do a have to do that for every third column manually?

So what I'm looking for is a way to automatically use autofill on every third column.

Comment: Can you just copy and paste the entire column c and stick it in column F? IF the formula is the same it would only take like 2 seconds to highlight the column and `Ctrl+V`. You could also do this through VBA, but I can't imagine it would be quicker to write then it would be to just copypasta

Comment: The formula is in each third column. I just need to paste down the formula in each column to match the products in the rows. And there are a couple of hundred columns to be pasted down, so if it could be done with VBA it would safe me lots of time.

Comment: Does each group of three columns have the same number of rows? Is there any data beneath that data, or is it the only data on the sheet?

Comment: Each row is 1 product,  its specs are in the columns. However,  not all specs are set for all products, so although all the formulas have to be filled to the last row, the rows contain empty cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code assume you have the formula (you want to autofill the column with) on each 3rd column at row 2.

```
Sub Autofill_every_nth_column()
Dim RangeToFill As String

For i = 3 To 150 Step 3 'start from column 3 (i.e. column "C") and loop to column 150 (i.e. column "ET"). After every loop it jump 3 columns. So first loop it will autofill Column C, then autofill Column F etc.

    RangeToFill = Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, i)).Select 'Cell formula is located. This mean at Row 2 and column i, where i is the number the loop is at
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(200, i)) 'Autofill formula from row 2 to row 200.

    Next 'Jump to next loop.

End Sub
```

I wrote some comments so you hopefully can modify it for your purpose. Remember that autofill function in excel only autofill if there are values in cells. So even if you express:

```
Destination:=Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(200, i)) 'Autofill formula from row 2 to row 200.
```

It will only loop to the last row where there are values (and maximum to row 200).

Comment: Looks great, thanks, I''l try it out tomorrow. And thanks for mentioning about the empty values. Hadn't thought of that. However, my formula in C2, F2 and so on return an empty string if A2, D2 is empty. I can of course have the formula return 'dummy content' for the sake of auto fill. I can later on remove 'dummy content' with find and replace.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I understood my suggested solution for blank items woudn't work. I now found blanks and replaced them with dummy content in each first column, after seleting them with another macro. Then I used your macro to copy down the formula.

Comment: Np, So happy it worked for you :)!!! Perfect!! Yes, with autofill one have to be extra careful with blank values. 
A better nested loop could have copy each value and then paste it, but this was the quickest I could think of :).